# Emulator's camera built-in app buggy in Froyo / 2.2?

Tags: android, camera, emulation

the Emulator's camera worked fine for taking pictures in 2.1 Eclair. What did not work was recording videos, obviously.
Now running an app which worked merely flawless on 2.1 Emulator causes the camera app to crash. I fire up an intent to launch it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(TEMP_PHOTO_FILE)));
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

This starts the camera app but after a few seconds it crashes. The output is:

```
06-01 09:57:15.593: DEBUG/libEGL(5212): egl.cfg not found, using default config
06-01 09:57:15.593: DEBUG/libEGL(5212): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
06-01 09:57:15.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5212): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 11
06-01 09:57:15.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5212): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
06-01 09:57:15.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:760)
06-01 09:57:15.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:916)
06-01 09:57:15.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1246)
06-01 09:57:15.733: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5212):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)
```

Actually I just wanted to see if the bug which made you receive a small image from the camera even though EXTRA_OUTPUT was specified has been fixed in FroYo. Unfortunately, I don't even get to test it.
Does anyone run into similiar issues?

Thanks,
Steff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks there's a mistmatch between the EGLConfig the Camera is requesting and the EGLConfigs currently supported by the s/w GL renderer that comes in Froyo. See if you can request an RGB565 EGL Config.

Moreover, the below changes worked for me. It basically remove the Stencil buffer out of the EGLConfig as that configuration seems to be not supported at all in the s/w GL renderer in Froyo. Add the original config back if you're testing on real devices such as the Droid.

diff --git a/src/com/android/camera/ui/GLRootView.java   b/src/com/android/camera/ui/GLRootView.java
index d8ae0f8..545c66a

```
--- a/src/com/android/camera/ui/GLRootView.java  
+++ b/src/com/android/camera/ui/GLRootView.java  
@@ -174,7 +174,8 @@ public class GLRootView extends GLSurfaceView  

     private void initialize() {  
         mFlags |= FLAG_INITIALIZED;  
-        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 4);  
+        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);  
         getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);  
         setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Comment: Where do i find this find? Where's that "a/src/..." located? Can't find it in the Eclipse, SDK or Workspace folder. Google links to this topic and multiple other persons not finding this file either.

Comment: @JamesCameron the source code is inside the packages/apps/Camera folder. It comes as part of the Android tree when building Android from source.

Answer (score 0):

emulator 2.2 is broken.
Please vote for this: [code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9376](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9376) so we can get a fix.

Workaround: Create an AVD with 2.1 as the target.