# Trouble running simple app.

Tags: android

I'm new at this. Go easy.

My code so far looks like this.

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.hardware.Camera;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String fmode = "Not Supported";
    Camera cam = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
    if (p.getFlashMode() != null)
        {fmode = p.getFlashMode();}
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(fmode);
    setContentView(tv);
}
}
```

When I run the program, I get the message stating that The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. If I comment out these four lines...

```
//Camera cam = Camera.open();
//Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
//if (p.getFlashMode() != null)
    //{fmode = p.getFlashMode();}
```

then the code runs fine and I get the "Not Supported" message. Then if I uncomment the first line where I declare the Camera object, it crashes again.

Feel free to be verbose, I'm in learning mode and would like all the information I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste DDMS logs so that we can see the exception?

Comment: For a new user, have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html). Logcat is where your logs and all the android system logs including exception strings are printed. It you do as it describes on the page or open DDMS it will show the log. Most likely you haven't got the manifest permission for accessing the camera.

Comment: I don't know what DDMS is and I don't know how to open a command line for my emulator. Like I said, new at this. Somehow I suspected my manifest file.

Comment: If you suspect it's your manifest file, please see my answer below to add the camera permission.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you missed adding the camera permission in your AndroidManifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
      <application ...>
      .
      .
      .
      </application>
</manifest>
```

If that's not the case:

[Why does the android emulator camera stop unexpectedly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044836/why-does-the-android-emulator-camera-stop-unexpectedly)

Comment: Camera permission in the manifest was the problem. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar using a camera in apps but I found you a great tutorial that can help you on your way towards your solution.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

I hope this is helpful for you and may you find what you need :) if not, I'll make a test app myself and help you further

And like someone else stated above, some permissions must be added to use the camera, you can find those here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are needed to allow access to certain features in android. Did you put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` in your android manifest to have access to the camera.