# Failure trying to reinstall new Camera.apk to android emulator 2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948809/emulators-camera-built-in-app-buggy-in-froyo-2-2), I tried to modify GLRootView.java and reinstall new Camera.apk; however, some errors show up when I tried to uninstall the old Camera.apk. Do you know what's the issue and how to resolve it?

```
$ ./adb remount 

remount succeeded

$ ./adb shell rm /system/app/Camera.apk

rm failed for /system/app/Camera.apk, Directory not empty

$ ./adb uninstall com.android.camera
```

Failure

reinstall from eclipse

```
[2011-05-08 17:41:43 - Camera] Uploading Camera.apk onto device 'emulator-5554' 
[2011-05-08 17:41:43 - Camera] Installing Camera.apk... [2011-05-08 17:42:11 - Camera] 
Re-installation failed due to different application signatures. [2011-05-08 17:42:11 - 
Camera] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will 
remove the application data! [2011-05-08 17:42:11 - Camera] Please execute 'adb 
uninstall com.android.camera' in a shell. [2011-05-08 17:42:11 - Camera] Launch 
canceled!
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error. I think it can be connected with system image size.

Try to start an emulator with parameter `-partition-size 150`. In my case it solved the issue.

There is a tutorial with pictures ["How to install Android market into SDK"](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/10004/accessing-android-market-from-android-sdk/) describing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

If that failed for some reason, type in the command prompt:

```
adb remount
adb shell
```

and in inside the shell:

```
cd /system/app
rm Camera.apk
```

Use it only in the emulator!!!

Comment: still the same error.
`$ ./adb remount`
remount succeeded

`$ ./adb devices`

List of devices attached 

emulator-5554 device

`$ ./adb shell`

`# cd /system/app`

`# rm Camera.apk`

rm failed for Camera.apk, Directory not empty

Comment: @angelokh try recreating the AVD

Comment: Do you think creating AVD from Eclipse makes any difference? I tried that, the error is still the same.