# Fixed Android 2.2 Camera.apk for emulator available for download?

Tags: android, android-emulator, camera, android-2.2-froyo

The Android 2.2 Camera in the emulator is broken as noted in...
[Emulator's camera built-in app buggy in Froyo / 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948809/emulators-camera-built-in-app-buggy-in-froyo-2-2)

And discussion of rebuilding and installing an updated Camera.apk can be seen here...
[Failure trying to reinstall new Camera.apk to android emulator 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931444/tried-to-reinstall-new-camera-apk-to-android-emulator-2-2-but-it-failed?answertab=active#tab-top)

Also details of the fix found here...
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9376

I was wondering if somebody knows of a fixed version of the Camera.apk file that I can download to use in my emulator?  It seems like it can be quite a time consuming process to download and then build all of the android source to implement this fix if it's been done already by others.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm "programming" Android and testing with the 2.2 emulator which has broken camera functionality.  Sounds pretty programming related to me, but ok then... I guess testing doesn't fall into that category.

Comment: Testing certainly falls into StackOverflow territory. This question has nothing to do with testing. This question is "please somebody do something for free for me, because I don't want to spend the time to do it myself". If the question and any answers do not help advance people's knowledge of programming, StackOverflow is not the right place for it. With respect to your problem, I suspect you will need a full AVD, as I'm not sure that firmware APKs can be successfully replaced in an emulator. Usually, I test camera stuff with hardware.

Comment: I'm not asking anybody to do anything "free" for me.  I'm asking if there's a known source to a fixed .apk file available online somewhere.  Read the question more carefully next time.